# Editing Referrer Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

How would I change the HTTP Referrer data?

e.g.

```
 header("Location: http://www.google.com/; Referrer: http://www.google.com/admins.php");
```

That doesn't seem to specify work.

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to change Referer from the server. At least, I don't think it does. *edit* - yes, "Referer" (spelled that way) is a request header field but not a response header field.

Comment: You mean for an Ajax request?

Comment: This seems to be PHP code. Show us the Javascript you've got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to do this with Ajax? If that is the case, then...

With a plain vanilla `XMLHttpRequest`, you'd use `setRequestHeader`:

```
request.setRequestHeader('Referer', 'http://whatever.you/want-it/to?be');
```

With `jQuery.ajax`, you'd specify the `headers` option:

```
headers: {
    'Referer': 'http://whatever.you/want-it/to?be'
}
```